# Filter unmerged files which have conflict markers

Tags: git, git-diff, git-merge-conflict

I develop tools for manage git repositories.
I have to develop custom git commit command , 
it will be a wrapper for native `git commit` with some checks.
On my custom commit i can call git commit when and only when repository doesn't have a conflict.
So i have to filter unmerged files and check if they doesn't have a conflict markers , such us <<<<<<< , ====== and >>>>>>>.

For example:

```
I have  a conflicted files:

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   file_a.txt
        both modified:   file_b.txt
        both modified:   file_c.txt

Each files contains conflicted markers.

Let's assume that i merged *file_a.txt,file_b.txt*  and remove markers.
But *file_c.txt* still conflicting, and i can't call git add .

let's summarize:
    I can commit changes only when repository doesn have conflict and conflict markers.
    I think command: 
      git diff-index --name-only -G "^(<|=|>){7} " HEAD --diff-filter=U
    can help me , but i don't understand why it not works.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if I understood your use case, and why the "normal" way to see conflicted files isn't applicable for you.  That is, normally you simply use git status, which will show staged changes for each successfully-merged file and unstaged changes for each conflicted file (i.e. each file that contains conflict markers).  So as long as you `add` each file when, and only when, you've resolved its conflicts, it shouldn't be an issue.  Perhaps if I know your situation where this doesn't work, it will make clear what other approach might still work...

Comment: I updated my issues description. Thanks.